# RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE with Dungeons Demo (In-app Billing ) at http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

Tags: android, google-play

I test the Dungeons demo on Motorola Droid 2 and get an error. In response to a CHECK_BILLING_SUPPORTED request, I get RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE.

I have product list on Android Market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by use keystore with information below:

Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
Keystore password: "android"
Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
Key password: "android"
CN: "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"

Export application (.apk file) use this debug keystore and upload it to Android market.

Answer (score 0):

Check please, that you have Android Market Application v. 2.3.0.